# How do I set a default group with django-authopenid?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-registration, django-authopenid

I have a django app that uses django-authopenid as the sole registration method.  I have `registration` in my installed apps, which django-authopenid uses.  An ideal solution would allow me to run arbitrary code on the user object when they register.  I can't directly modify the code for `django-authopenis` or `registration`.

Let me know if I need to add any more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `models.py` you could bind the [post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


def default_group(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='your default group name'))
post_save.connect(default_group, sender=User)
```

If in doubt, read the [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) documentation.

Comment: Thanks!  I haven't used signals before, but this'll be very helpful in other parts of my app too.  :-)